# How to build a release archive with rebar3 together with lager

Tags: erlang-otp, lager, rebar3

I am trying to build an OTP release with rebar3.  Under the project there are multiple applications.  And all those applications will use lager as a logging framework.   So I tried the rebar.config like this

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info,
            {i, "apps"}]
}.

{deps, [lager]}.

{relx, [{release, { myrel, "0.0.1" },
         [app1,
          app2,
          sasl]},
        {sys_config, "./config/sys.config"},
        {vm_args, "./config/vm.args"},
        {dev_mode, false},
        {include_erts, false},
        {extended_start_script, true}]
}.

{profiles, [{prod, [{relx, [{dev_mode, false},
                            {include_src, false},
                            {include_erts, true},
                            {system_libs, true}
                            ]}]
            }]
}.
```

The dependence likes this

```
===> Verifying dependencies...
├─ lager─3.2.1 (hex package)
│  └─ goldrush─0.1.8 (hex package)
├─ app1─1.0.0 (project app)
└─ app2─0.1.0 (project app)
```

'rebar3 release' looks fine.  No error shown.

However, when I run 'rebar3 as prod tar', I found that there is no lager (and goldrush) included the archive (ie. myrel-0.0.1.tar.gz). Therefore when I run it in production system with command 'bin/myrel console', I got the following error..

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 23-Nov-2016::13:23:01 ===
** Generic server sccp_user terminating 
** Last message in was {set,1,undefined}
** When Server state == {su_state,lookup}
** Reason for termination == 
** {'module could not be loaded',
       [{lager_config,get,[{lager_event,loglevel},{0,[]}],[]},
.....
```

Any idea how to solve this ?